# cvs update all changes and just changes

Tags: cvs

Full checking out of project takes ~50 minutes due to connection issues.

So I want to call something like `update`, but which will delete all folders&files that were deleted since last `checkout`, and will upload all folders&files that were uploaded since last `checkout`.

And all conflicts should be forced to overlap local version by server version, without `merge`.

Another words, I need to checkout files and folders that were changed, and not touch ones that were not changed. And delete all files and folders that were deleted since last `checkout`.

Is it possible with CVS?

Manuals I've found do not answer this question.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why can't you use `cvs update`? Also, have you tried using compression to speed things up: e.g. `cvs -z9 co`, `cvs -z9 update`.

Comment: `update` is not deleting folders that were created local, but not exists on server. Also `update` is performing merge on conflicts, but I need just use server's version of files.
Thank you for `-z9` option, I will try it

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you want. You want to pick up all changes from the server, except where these changes touch files that you have modified/added in which case you want to completely ignore what the server has and use your own version. That is simply not possible with any one or two CVS commands. You will need to write a script to do it. If you write the script and have problems, you can ask for help on stack overflow, but you will need to make a serious honest attempt at it yourself first.